# Получение данных из БД

Tags: java, android, c++, sql

Есть у меня бд (mssql)
Получаю из неё данные, в программе, которую написал на C++
Так же хочу получить из неё данные для приложения на Java (под Android)
Как это реализовать? И стоит ли делать через mssql, ибо в основном, как я понял это делается через sqlite

Comment: э-э-э, как это sqlite и m$sql это разные вещи. Например, даже в принципе организации базы, как таковой

Answer (score 2):

если вы хотите научиться работать с базами через java, то я думаю как минимум стоит для начала ознакомиться с интерфейсом jdbc и уже плясать от этого. вот неплохой [материал](http://www.javaportal.ru/java/tutorial/tutorialJDBC/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

Вы путаете понятия. sqlite - такой же движок базы как и mssql, а никак не ORM или что то подобное.

Далее стоит уточнить где будет находиться ваша база, удаленно или прямо на устройстве.

Если удаленно то вам, скорее всего, придется написать некоторый вебсервис, к которому через rest будет обращаться ваше android-приложение.

Если прямо на устройстве, то смотрите на различные ORM для андроид, вроде storio, active-android, realm и прочие.